# Is it OK to include Java Swing with JSP?

Tags: java, swing, jsp

I tried using `Swing` code in a `JSP` page. To my surprise it does work well and fine.

But I cannot judge if it is OK to use `Swing` with JSP?

Basically I want to display some pop up reports from **Database**. I was thinking to display a `JFrame` pop up/ applet to do the trick.

But do a web browser require any *additional* plugin for this?

Or is it fine to do such a thingy? Any guidance will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always remember that every java fragment you insert into your JSP is executed server-side, so it can be deceitful (it may seem to work in your development local machine, but it is only because the server and the client side are running on the same box).

The proper way to do this would be to write an Applet and include it into your page - this way, the browser will download it to client side and run it there.  You should subclass JApplet (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html) and then you will be able to use Swing components at will

Comment: Also consider deploying via [tag:java-web-start].

Comment: That would be if I needed to deploy a pure swing application to my users - in that case you are right, Web Start is a good option and one I have used.  Since OP said they had JSP, I suggested to use an applet because I thought it was the option the most similar to what I imagined they wanted

Answer (score 3):

The library works but your controls will never be shown at the client side (browser) but at the server (if it is that you have a working window service: Ms Windows, X11, Xorg,...).

I don't think that is a good practice and I would only use `Swing` library classes not to show GUI components but to use some classes to store special objects such as [ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) to store icons. But never to try to paint them.

I have a project where I use [JLaTeXMath](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/jlatexmath/) to generate a PNG within a JSP representing some math equations, in this context, I use `javax.swing.JLabel` to generate the image:

```
    TeXFormula formula = new TeXFormula(texCode);
    TeXIcon texImg = formula.createTeXIcon(TeXConstants.STYLE_DISPLAY, 25);
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(texImg.getIconWidth(), texImg.getIconHeight(), 
            BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    texImg.paintIcon(new JLabel(),img.getGraphics(), 0, 0);
    try {
        OutputStream os = res.getOutputStream();
        res.setContentType("image/png");
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", os);
        os.close();
        res.flushBuffer();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.warn("LaTeX renderer: " + ex.toString() + "\t" + "Msg: " + ex.getMessage());
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Just as a comment to Pablo's nice piece of code, this kind of things, when done in server side, will make it necessary that you start your app server in headless mode (see http://www.ve.com/kavachart/solutions/xwindows.html)

Answer (score 2):

> the JSP would run on the server,and probably display the GUI there,
>   but why would you want that? In the meantime, the person at the client
>   who submitted the request would be sitting there waiting for somebody
>   at the server end to close the Swing window so the JSP could get on
>   with its work.

So i would say that it is not feasible.

Comment: Wow, this would have been the biggest "Works on my machine!" debacle ever if this had been put in an actual application.

Comment: Yeah I tried this once.. and I need 4 people to help me run the application.